# how to rotate text labels in Apache POI XSSFChart

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I'm trying to generate an excel document that contains Bar chats using Apache POI library. I want to rotate the text in x-axis labels, but there is no option to rotate the text. This is what I have tried so far

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing
                .createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, graphStartColumn, graphStartRow, graphEndColumn, graphEndRow);
 XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setTitle(report.getX().getLegend());
bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties().setBold(true);
// here I'm trying to add text rotation to x-axis labels, but I don't see an option in axis

XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setTitle(report.getY().get(0).getLegend());
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
```

Does anyone know how to rotate text on the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported by `XDDFCategoryAxis`. But of course the underlying `ooxml-schemas` classes support it.

So we could get the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTextBody` from the category axis and set rotation property there. Because of the `bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties()` setting, we can be sure, there is a `TxPr` already and also a `BodyPr`. So we need no `null` check for those.

Only additional challenge are the values of the rotation. We can set rotation from 0 to 90 degrees and 0 to -90 degrees. There 90 degrees is a value of 5400000.

Example:

```
...
  bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties().setBold(true);

  java.lang.reflect.Field _ctCatAx = XDDFCategoryAxis.class.getDeclaredField("ctCatAx");
  _ctCatAx.setAccessible(true);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx ctCatAx = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx)_ctCatAx.get(bottomAxis);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTextBody text = ctCatAx.getTxPr(); // there is a TxPr already because of bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties()

  int rotAngle = 0;
  //int plus90Deg = 5400000; rotAngle = plus90Deg;
  //int minus90Deg = -5400000; rotAngle = minus90Deg;
  //int plus45Deg = (int)Math.round(5400000/2d); rotAngle = plus45Deg;
  int minus45Deg = (int)Math.round(-5400000/2d); rotAngle = minus45Deg;

  text.getBodyPr().setRot(rotAngle); // there is a BodyPr already because of bottomAxis.getOrAddTextProperties()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight simplification of the answer provided by @Axel Richter.

```
// Starting with the chart and axis.
XSSFChart chart = ...
XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = ...

// triggers creation of TxtPr and BodyPr used when setting the rotation
categoryAxis.getOrAddTextProperties();

// set the rotation angle
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray(0).getTxPr().getBodyPr().setRot(-5400000);
```

And for reference the rotation angle is defined as 1/60000 of a degree, so set the value to degrees*60000.